# how to get the current date until a specific time in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a system to record the daily attendance of some workers to the company.

The laboral day change when get 6:00am of the next day, it have a the next work cycle lapse.

**Example:**

```
January 30, 2018
Start: 6am.
End of day: January 31, 6am

January 31, 2018
Start: 6am
End of Day: February 1, 6am.
```

**The question is:**

¿How i can get the current date until specific time in PHP?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: @Phil i edited, want set the day start at 6am of the day, and day end, 6am of the next day

Comment: I wouldn't modify the PHP date system, as a) the easiest way is the zend API, and b) You will likely need the unmodified system in the future, what I would do is make your own (or set the time zone 6 hours ahead, but that's an equally terrible idea)

Comment: That sounds like you want to set a different time zone, however that you say "format" confuses me... you know what date format is, right? - Anyway, if you have a date and you want to know the day, you could read the day to a variable from the date, then check the hour and if it is before 6am offset the day variable. Edit: you could encapsulate that on a function or a class.

Comment: @Theraot, some like that, because now im saving day, month and year in separate variables, i only wnat that the system save the assistance of the day 30 at 5.35am for the day 29

Comment: Sounds like you just want a date _diff_ and there's plenty of questions and answers for that problem

Comment: Does your time zone use day light saving time? You can [get in trouble by working dates by hand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY), better be careful on what happen on those edge cases.

Comment: @Theraot im from Venezuela, i dont know xD jejeje

Comment: Countries near the equator do not have need for day light saving time. Meaning that you are fine. I did double check the mess Chavez did back in [2007](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/venezuela-enters-half-hour-zone.html) and [2016](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/venezuela-change-timezone.html), he basically moved the clock from UTC-4:00 to UTC-4:30 and then back to UTC-4:00. Thankfully he did not institude day light saving time (must have thought that is an imperialist policy) although if you are working with date around those ranges, double check your math.

Comment: Oh i get it, yes, Chavez change it, in "real utc" 6am, us 5:30am, something like that, now Maduro change it again. When i use whatsapp it says "6pm" but the messages in the net says "5:30pm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a timestamp. I'm manually defining one here, but you can use any date string or whatever format is available:

```
$ts = '2017-03-14 05:15';
```

And check the 24-hour format hour value:

```
date('H', strtotime($ts))
```

If the value is less than your boundary, you can subtract any value greater than 6 (day start boundary) and less than 23 (avoid errors due to daylight savings) hours, in seconds, to roll back to the previous day ... 12 is safe:

```
$effectiveDate = date('H', strtotime($ts)) < 6 ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ts)-(60*60*12)) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ts))
```

In this case, `effectiveDate` would have the value of `2017-03-13`

Comment: but i change it to 60*60*24 because. with 12 get an error, change the hour

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is subtract six hours from both timestamps, although I don't recommend messing with the record for when employees clock in and out, because a) it might be illegal, and b) it doesn't make any sense.

If you insist on this, just do this `$mydate-= 60 * 60 * 6`